# Is it necessary for me to join my threads in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, join

I'm creating an asp.net application and I'm trying to use separate threads to allow users to upload files to a server (there seems to be a lot of conflicts when two users do this at the same time). When a user hits the page, I have a pageLoad function which handles my logic:

```
public void UploadFile()
{
    //code to upload a file
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(UploadFile);

    t1.Start();
    t1.Join();     
}
```

My question is: is it really necessary to join the thread that is created? From some of the other posts, it seems to be important to join a thread so that it isn't terminated unexpectedly.

and if there are several people running this code at once, will "t1.Join()" join the current thread that they created?

Comment: Calling `Join` is essentially to wait for that thread to terminate, so if you don't care about that you don't need to call `Join` on it.

Comment: ok, so I I should keep it? Would it be possible for my Page_Load function to finish before my UploadFile function finishes?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the `Join` your `Page_Load` handler will terminate without waiting for the thread to run to completion, which is fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm creating an asp.net application and I'm trying to use separate threads to allow users to upload files to a server

It is generally unwise to kick off your own threads in ASP.Net.  Such threads can be terminated unexpectedly, for example if the app domain recycles.

The code `UploadFile` would run entirely on the server.  It's not clear what that code does, but it would not be able to start a new interaction with the user's browser.

Have a look at this Microsoft documentation that illustrates how to write code to allow a file to be uploaded to the server.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246

> it seems to be important to join a thread so that it isn't terminated unexpectedly

A background thread will terminate if its program terminates.  It is generally advisable to have threads terminate on their own, either because their work completes or in reaction to a signal of some kind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(UploadFile);

    t1.Start();
    t1.Join();     
}
```

This code will still block the Page_Load event.  Even though it starts a new thread, it then waits for that thread to complete before returning.  If you remove Join(), the handler will return right after starting the thread `t1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use thread to upload files, asp.net runtime actually is a multiple thread environment.